# Trying to run application in the background (Minimized/Screen Locked/Removed from running application)

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, background

I am writing an android application which will trigger the SMS once a missed call is detected. So far I am able to detect missed call and send the SMS to the caller.

If I run my app, (Turned on the SWITCH (like a smart switch) that checks for the ringing call and detects missed call), and then someone is calling and if it is a missed call, the SMS is fired correctly. 
If I minimize my app (Do not lock phone) and open Instagram/Other app, then also SMS is going to caller.

BUT,

when my app (Smart switch to enable this feature is ON), but I close my app, no SMS sent.
when my app is minimized (Screen Locked), no message fired. (Smart switch ON)
when my app is opened (Screen locked), no message fired. (Smart switch ON)

I am new to android. Please help me, I want to keep my app running if my SMART SWITCH is on, the my app will continue to monitor missed call and fire SMS to caller irrespective of APP in background or not, screen locked or not as long as my Smart switch is ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to start a service and it worked, for background to work, we need a foreground.

```
public class myservices extends Service
```

{
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //To open the MainActivity onClick
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

```
    Intent busy = new Intent(this, InterceptCall.class);
    Intent driving = new Intent(this, InterceptCall.class);
    Intent meeting = new Intent(this, InterceptCall.class);
    busy.putExtra("mode","busy");
    driving.putExtra("mode", "driving");
    meeting.putExtra("mode", "meeting");
    PendingIntent busyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, busy, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //For mini icon in notification bar
    PendingIntent drivingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, driving, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //For mini icon in notification bar
    PendingIntent meetingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, meeting, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //For mini icon in notification bar

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Smart Mode is on ")
            .setContentText("Drag down to display modes.")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setColor(Color.MAGENTA)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pingedlogo)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Busy", busyIntent)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Driving", drivingIntent)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Meeting", meetingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first you need to have the permission about task

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Code example

```
 Thread(Runnable {
        // a potentially time consuming task
        val bitmap = processBitMap("image.png")
        imageView.post {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }).start()
```

Also you need to

I recommend to look up the next page

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

[Services overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

This is how I solved it.

public class myservices extends Service
{
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //To open the MainActivity onClick
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

```
    Intent busy = new Intent(this, InterceptCall.class);
    Intent driving = new Intent(this, InterceptCall.class);
    Intent meeting = new Intent(this, InterceptCall.class);
    busy.putExtra("mode","busy");
    driving.putExtra("mode", "driving");
    meeting.putExtra("mode", "meeting");
    PendingIntent busyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, busy, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //For mini icon in notification bar
    PendingIntent drivingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, driving, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //For mini icon in notification bar
    PendingIntent meetingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, meeting, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //For mini icon in notification bar

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Smart Mode is on ")
            .setContentText("Drag down to display modes.")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setColor(Color.MAGENTA)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pingedlogo)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Busy", busyIntent)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Driving", drivingIntent)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Meeting", meetingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Also when I am removing my app from background (onDestroy getting called), but I still need to detect missed call since my smart mode switch is ON.

Comment: can you shom me what is going on?

Comment: Hi @Alejandro, I was able to work it out, I used foreground services.

Comment: I added in question, please check